# How to create KVM with veewee?

Tags: kvm

I am looking for a short tutorial on how to create a *KVM* with *veewee*? I would like to use *veewee* to construct OS that would fit my application needs

Answer (score 0):

Update:
 on the veewee github page, you can find now a decent documentation:
https://github.com/jedi4ever/veewee/blob/master/doc/kvm.md

```
I will use a different solution: 

 1. start an image with kvm
 2. Use chef solo to customize the machine
 3. Save an image to use it as a template for others
```